# xtable in pgfSweave (on lyx) : output=tex is invalid?

Tags: errors, lyx, sweave, r

Many tutorials online say that to include a table in `Sweave` one should write something like this:

```
<<output=tex>>=
require(xtable)
stuff
xtable(stuff)
@
```

That makes sense. But when I do that in `LyX 2.1` on `Ubuntu 10.04` with `texlive-full 2011` installed (and `pgfSweave 2.10`), I get the following error:

```
invalid value for 'output' : tex
```

Comment: `result=tex` similar error

Answer (score 1):

Should work with `results` instead of `result` or `output`.

```
<<results=tex>>=
```

The [Sweave documentation](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/) may also be helpful.

Comment: Slowly plodding my way through that. There are like 4 PDF's of necessary background for `Sweave`, each of them in an obscure style.